# Change GNuPG passphrase using a script

Tags: gnupg, symfony-process

I am struggling to change a *GnuPG* private key passphrase with a script.

This is as far as I get: it returns that the process was successful at the end, but it doesn't change the passphrase. Any other form of options to *gpg* result in errors and no passphrase change.

Anyone have any hints? I'll accept answers using Symfony's process component or without - I just need to get it working.

Python/Bash/Expect answers also welcome. It should work without exposing the passphrase in the command line.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\InputStream;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$fingerprint = '0123456789ABCDEF';
$previous = 'secret';
$passphrase = 'moresecret';

$process = new Process(
    [
        'gpg',
        '--passphrase-fd=0',
        '--pinentry-mode=loopback',
        '--change-passphrase',
        $fingerprint,
    ]
);

$input = new InputStream();
$process->setInput($input);

$process->start();

$input->write($previous."\n");
$input->write($passphrase."\n");
$input->close();

foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
    if ($process::OUT === $type) {
        echo "\nSTDOUT: $data";
    } else {
        echo "\nSTDERR: $data";
    }
}

return $process->isSuccessful();
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with *expect* and the *Symfony Process* component.

Save this *expect* script on the filesystem:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn gpg --pinentry-mode=loopback --change-passphrase $env(GPG_USERID)
set timeout -1
expect "Enter passphrase: " { send "$env(GPG_PREVIOUS)\r" }
expect "Enter passphrase: " { send "$env(GPG_PASSPHRASE)\r" }
interact
```

Use the following code to execute and analyse the result of the script run:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$userid = 'user@example.com';
$previous = 'secret';
$passphrase = 'moresecret';

$path = realpath(__DIR__ . '/path/to/your/script.exp');

$process = new Process(
    [
        $path,
    ],
    null,
    [
        'GPG_USERID' => $userid,
        'GPG_PREVIOUS' => $previous,
        'GPG_PASSPHRASE' => $passphrase,
    ]
);

$process->start();

$success = true;

$process->wait(function ($type, $buffer) use (&$success) {
    if (
        Process::OUT === $type
        && strpos($buffer, 'Bad passphrase') !== false
    ) {
        $success = false;
    }
});

return $process->isSuccessful() && $success;
```

*gnupg* returns exit code 0 even when the previous passphrase is entered incorrectly. It reports this on *stdout*, not *stderr*.

I parse the output looking for `Bad passphrase` and incorporate that into the success check at the end.

I now have a perfectly scripted *change passphrase* method, without compromising security by using command-line parameters.